# getting a 'output not utf-8' error when trying to print a simple list from a text file

Tags: python

I have saved a text file containing a list with ANSI encoding in notepad.

when I try to display the list using the below script in Python, it displays the first item in the list and then gives the "output not utf-8" error message.

```
with open("animals.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for animal in content:
    print animal
```

is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Tongue in cheek answer - use Python 3!

Comment: We'd need to see 'animals.txt' to see what is really going on.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7. Will changing to Python 3 solve the problem?

Comment: @fassetar Really? The example code given works in Python 3.3.2 (although obviously with a mockup animals.txt. I believe the problem lies somewhere within Python 2.x's horrible unicode support.

Comment: So yes, switching to Python 3 will solve this problem, and if it is possible I would suggest you do so, otherwise you'll need to convert the lines you read to unicode before printing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading a byte string, then transferring those raw bytes straight to your output and your terminal or IDE console is complaining that the bytestream contain sequences that are illegal in UTF-8.

Use [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) to read the file into unicode data, then let Python encode the unicode values to your terminal codec automatically:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("animals.txt", 'r', encoding='mbcs') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for animal in content:
    print animal
```

or loop directly over the file:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("animals.txt", 'r', encoding='mbcs') as f:
    for animal in f:
        print animal
```

`mbcs` is the Python name for the Windows ANSI codepage:

> Windows only: Encode operand according to the ANSI codepage (CP_ACP)

Perhaps you meant a different, specific Windows codepage; in that case pick out the right `cp` codec, such as `cp1250` or `cp1252` for Microsoft's Western Europe Latin-1 variants.